# How can I keep my bootloader from disappearing?

Tags: dual-boot, grub, manjaro

I dual-boot Manjaro and Windows, via Grub and UEFI on a Lenovo Yoga C930, which uses Bitlocker and Secure Boot. I can successfully boot into Manjaro if I disable Secure Boot in BIOS, and I can also boot into Windows if I re-enable Secure Boot in BIOS. For reasons unknown, and seemingly at random, I'll just lose my Linux bootloader. I don't know whether it's getting deleted, or suddenly can't be recognized, or what, but I can't boot from it, and it doesn't show up as an option in BIOS.

I can manage to reinstall Grub by following the instructions on the Wiki, but eventually it will just disappear. What's going on, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't believe grub is deleted. I believe Windows might be deleting UEFI entries.

Comment: One solution is to install Windows in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and after that Linux (also in BIOS mode). During (major?) upgrades of Windows in UEFI mode I have had similar problems. But never with Windows installed in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out on my own. Turns out I had to use `efibootmgr` to manually create a new boot entry, and give it a high priority. So far, so good.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Windows is keeping your system "cancer-free".

[EDIT] You have two solutions, depending on which boot method you use, legacy and UEFI.

**Legacy:**

You can use `bcd` as a boot manager to launch Windows or Linux.

Assuming you have grub installed to `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1` is the Windows EFI partition

In Linux:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/linux.bin bs=512 count=1
```

In Windows:

```
bcdedit /create /d "Linux" /application bootsector
```

BCDEdit will return an alphanumeric identifier for this entry that I
will refer to as {ID} in the remaining steps. You’ll need to replace
{ID} by the actual returned identifier. An example of {ID} is
{d7294d4e-9837-11de-99ac-f3f3a79e3e93}. Next, let’s specify which
partition hosts a copy of the linux.bin file:

```
bcdedit /set {ID} device partition=c:
```

The path to our linux.bin file:

```
bcdedit /set {ID}  path \linux.bin
```

An entry to the displayed menu at boot time:

```
bcdedit /displayorder {ID} /addlast
```

and finally, let’s specify how long the menu choices will be displayed:

```
bcdedit /timeout 30
```

That’s it! Now reboot and you will be presented with menu where you can choose to boot to Windows or Linux. When you choose Linux, you’ll be taken to the it bootloader menu where you can choose to boot Linux.

https://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/

[EDIT]
**UEFI**

Your Windows system has a EFI partition from which it boots. In Linux, you mount that to `/boot`. Then, ensure your `grub.cfg` is looking-up the root parition using uuid (by default it does):  like, for example:  `linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-default root=UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1  quiet splash=silent`, if it does not, you use `blkid` to list the UUID of your root partition and adapt grub config in `/etc/grub.d`.

You write out your grub config to `/boot/boot/efi/EFI/manjaro/grub.cfg`

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/boot/efi/EFI/manjaro/grub.cfg
```

Reboot, you "should" be good to go.

Comment: It's not that grub has the wrong entry. It's that grub isn't recognized at all. The only way to get it back, that I've discovered, is to reinstall grub. What I'm trying to find is a way to prevent grub from disappearing in the first place.

Comment: Even with UEFI, it may be necessary to use bcdedit to change settings. I posted a link to an issue I had a couple of years ago in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this almost two years ago, with a dual boot of Trisquel Linux with Windows 8. I posted a question/answer [here](https://superuser.com/q/1298510/799549) on Super User (I was told at the time that dual-boot questions were off-topic on U&L, for some reason).

As you will see in those posts, the issue wasn't that Windows was deleting or over-writing GRUB, but it was periodically changing the UEFI settings to tell it to use the Windows bootloader, rather than GRUB. The solution was to use bcdedit in Windows, to set the default bootloader path to GRUB, which solved my problem.

I don't know if the same solution will work for you, but perhaps worth a try?

(also, I don't believe you need to have Secure Boot enabled to boot Windows. I boot into Windows 8 with it disabled just fine.)